# How to split DK1, DK2 & DK3/4&5,6&7+DK8.DK9-DK12 to DK14 into 14 rows?

Tags: sql, regex, pyspark, regexp-replace, databricks-sql

I want Deck_Info values to be split into multiple rows based on "","" or ""&"" or ""/"" or ""+"" or "".""

""-"" or ""TO"" or ""to"" it means a range. In this scenario we need to split the record into multiple based on the asked range and consider all of them as individual rows

Raw Data

| GUID | Deck_Info |
| --- | --- |
| 391 | DK1, DK2 |
| 392 | DK3 & DK4 |
| 393 | DK5/6 |
| 394 | DK7&8 |
| 395 | DK9, 10 & 11 |
| 396 | DK12+DK13 |
| 397 | DK14.DK15 |
| 398 | DK16-DK18 |
| 399 | DK18 TO DK20 |

Desired Query Output

| GUID | Deck_Info |
| --- | --- |
| 391 | DK1 |
| 391 | DK2 |
| 392 | DK3 |
| 392 | DK4 |
| 393 | DK5 |
| 393 | DK6 |
| 394 | DK7 |
| 394 | DK8 |
| 395 | DK9 |
| 395 | DK10 |
| 395 | DK11 |
| 396 | DK12 |
| 396 | DK13 |
| 397 | DK14 |
| 397 | DK15 |
| 398 | DK16 |
| 398 | DK17 |
| 398 | DK18 |
| 399 | DK18 |
| 399 | DK19 |
| 399 | DK20 |

I am working in databricks. Tried

```
explode(split(DeckInfo, '[,]'))
```

This worked well for ,
But, looking for an optimised SQL QUERY to take care of all above separators.

Comment: you normalize  only once, and so have to shoulder the transformation once, a you can not optimize it firther

Comment: I modified the answer to include the udf creation and applying to the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the following function as UDF and use it in a SQL query.

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import *



sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



data1 = [

["391","DK1 , DK2"],
["392","DK3 & DK4"],
["393","DK5 / 6"],
["394","DK7 & 8"],
["395","DK9 , 10 & 11"],
["396","DK12 + DK13"],
["397","DK14.DK15"],
["398","DK16 - DK18"],
["399","DK18 TO DK20"],
["3990","DK18     to    DK20"],
["400","DK16-DK20 + DK24 TO DK28"],

      ]




df1Columns = ["GUID","Deck_Info"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("Given Dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)





# Function to find insert position of K
def find_index(pos_list, K):
    # Traverse the array
    for i in range(len(pos_list)):
        # If arr[i] exceeds K
        if pos_list[i] > K:
            ## return previous position
            return i - 1
    # If all array elements are smaller
    return None


def extract_numbers(target_string):
    number_list_dict = []
    num_index = 0
    for match in re.finditer(r'\d+', target_string):
        dict_result = {"num_index": num_index, "match": match.group(), "start_index": match.start(), "end_index": match.end()}
        num_index += 1
        number_list_dict.append(dict_result)



    num_start_index_list = [my_dict["start_index"] for my_dict in number_list_dict]
    num_index_list = [my_dict["num_index"] for my_dict in number_list_dict]
    num_match_list = [int(my_dict["match"]) for my_dict in number_list_dict]

    to_string_list = []
    to_index = 0
    for match in re.finditer(r'TO|to', target_string):
        dict_result = {"to_index": to_index, "match": match.group(), "start_index": match.start(), "end_index": match.end()}
        to_index += 1
        to_string_list.append(dict_result)


    to_start_index_list = [my_dict["start_index"] for my_dict in to_string_list]
    to_index_list = [my_dict["to_index"] for my_dict in to_string_list]
    for ele in to_start_index_list:
        found_index = find_index(num_start_index_list, ele)
        match_index = num_index_list[found_index]
        num_match_list = num_match_list[:match_index] + list(range(num_match_list[match_index], num_match_list[match_index + 1])) + num_match_list[match_index + 1 : ]

    minus_string_list = []
    minus_index = 0
    for match in re.finditer(r'-', target_string):
        dict_result = {"minus_index": minus_index, "match": match.group(), "start_index": match.start(), "end_index": match.end()}
        minus_index +=1
        minus_string_list.append(dict_result)

    minus_start_index_list = [my_dict["start_index"] for my_dict in minus_string_list]
    minus_index_list = [my_dict["minus_index"] for my_dict in minus_string_list]

    for ele in minus_start_index_list:
        found_index = find_index(num_start_index_list, ele)
        match_index = num_index_list[found_index]
        num_match_list = num_match_list[:match_index] + list(range(num_match_list[match_index], num_match_list[match_index + 1])) + num_match_list[match_index + 1:]

    res_with_prefix = ["DK" + str(ele) for ele in num_match_list]

    return res_with_prefix



extract_numbers_udf = F.udf(extract_numbers,  ArrayType(StringType()))

""" Using UDF on SQL """
sqlContext.udf.register("extract_numbers_udf", extract_numbers_udf)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("given_table")

df1_array = sqlContext.sql("select GUID, extract_numbers_udf(Deck_Info) as Deck_Info_Array from given_table")
print("Dataframe after applying UDF")
df1_array.show(n=100, truncate=False)
df1_array.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_array")

print("Dataframe after exploding the array column")
df1_exploded = sqlContext.sql("select GUID, explode(Deck_Info_Array) as Deck_Info from df1_array")
df1_exploded.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given Dataframe
+----+------------------------+
|GUID|Deck_Info               |
+----+------------------------+
|391 |DK1 , DK2               |
|392 |DK3 & DK4               |
|393 |DK5 / 6                 |
|394 |DK7 & 8                 |
|395 |DK9 , 10 & 11           |
|396 |DK12 + DK13             |
|397 |DK14.DK15               |
|398 |DK16 - DK18             |
|399 |DK18 TO DK20            |
|3990|DK18     to    DK20     |
|400 |DK16-DK20 + DK24 TO DK28|
+----+------------------------+

Dataframe after applying UDF
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|GUID|Deck_Info_Array                                             |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|391 |[DK1, DK2]                                                  |
|392 |[DK3, DK4]                                                  |
|393 |[DK5, DK6]                                                  |
|394 |[DK7, DK8]                                                  |
|395 |[DK9, DK10, DK11]                                           |
|396 |[DK12, DK13]                                                |
|397 |[DK14, DK15]                                                |
|398 |[DK16, DK17, DK18]                                          |
|399 |[DK18, DK19, DK20]                                          |
|3990|[DK18, DK19, DK20]                                          |
|400 |[DK16, DK17, DK18, DK19, DK20, DK24, DK25, DK26, DK27, DK28]|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+

Dataframe after exploding the array column
+----+---------+
|GUID|Deck_Info|
+----+---------+
|391 |DK1      |
|391 |DK2      |
|392 |DK3      |
|392 |DK4      |
|393 |DK5      |
|393 |DK6      |
|394 |DK7      |
|394 |DK8      |
|395 |DK9      |
|395 |DK10     |
|395 |DK11     |
|396 |DK12     |
|396 |DK13     |
|397 |DK14     |
|397 |DK15     |
|398 |DK16     |
|398 |DK17     |
|398 |DK18     |
|399 |DK18     |
|399 |DK19     |
|399 |DK20     |
|3990|DK18     |
|3990|DK19     |
|3990|DK20     |
|400 |DK16     |
|400 |DK17     |
|400 |DK18     |
|400 |DK19     |
|400 |DK20     |
|400 |DK24     |
|400 |DK25     |
|400 |DK26     |
|400 |DK27     |
|400 |DK28     |
+----+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the same problem but using a scala native udf which are faster in execution. I converted the above python UDF to scala function and packaged it in a jar and provide that jar to SparkSession in pyspark.

Repository : https://github.com/dineshdharme/pyspark-native-udfs/

To build the jar : run  `sbt assembly`

Here's source of the scala native UDF fuction.

```
package com.help.udf

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1
import util.control.Breaks._


class SplitExtractValues extends UDF1[String, Array[String]] {

  def find_index(list: List[Int], k:Int): Int ={
    var foundIndex = -1
    breakable {

      for (ii <- list.indices) {
          if(list(ii) > k){
            foundIndex = ii - 1
            break;
          }
      }
    }
    foundIndex
  }


  override def call(givenString: String): Array[String] = {

    val regexInteger = "\\d+".r

    val allMatches = regexInteger.findAllMatchIn(givenString).toList
    //println("all matches only strings", allMatches)
    //println("all matches with all details", allMatches.map(ele => "start="  + ele.start +" end=" + ele.end + " matched="+ ele.matched))
    val num_start_index_list =  allMatches.map(ele => ele.start)
    val num_index_list =  allMatches.zipWithIndex.map(ele => ele._2)
    var num_match_list =  allMatches.map(ele => ele.matched.toInt)


    val regexRangeTO = "TO".r
    val allMatchesRangeTO = regexRangeTO.findAllMatchIn(givenString).toList
    val TO_start_index_list = allMatchesRangeTO.map(ele => ele.start)

    val regexRangeto = "to".r
    val allMatchesRangeto = regexRangeto.findAllMatchIn(givenString).toList
    val to_start_index_list = allMatchesRangeto.map(ele => ele.start)

    val regexRangeMinus = "-".r
    val allMatchesRangeMinus = regexRangeMinus.findAllMatchIn(givenString).toList
    val minus_start_index_list = allMatchesRangeMinus.map(ele => ele.start)

    val all_range_matches = TO_start_index_list ++ to_start_index_list ++ minus_start_index_list

    for (jj <- all_range_matches.indices) {

      val ele = all_range_matches(jj)

      //println("num_match_list  ", num_match_list)
      //println("to_start_index_list  ", all_range_matches)
      //println("ele  ", ele)
      val found_index = find_index(num_start_index_list, ele)
      //println("found index", found_index)

      val match_index = num_index_list(found_index)
      num_match_list = num_match_list.slice(0, match_index) ++ Range(num_match_list(match_index), num_match_list(match_index + 1)).toList ++ num_match_list.slice(match_index + 1, num_match_list.length)

    }

    //println("final num match list = ", num_match_list)

    num_match_list.map(ele => "DK" + ele).toArray

  }
}
```

Following is the pyspark script which registers the above function from the jar.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import re
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


## Download the jar from this location.
# https://github.com/dineshdharme/pyspark-native-udfs/tree/main/releases

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/pyspark-native-udfs-assembly-0.1.0.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)



data1 = [

["391","DK1 , DK2"],
["392","DK3 & DK4"],
["393","DK5 / 6"],
["394","DK7 & 8"],
["395","DK9 , 10 & 11"],
["396","DK12 + DK13"],
["397","DK14.DK15"],
["398","DK16 - DK18"],
["399","DK18 TO DK20"],
["3990","DK18     to    DK20"],
["400","DK16-DK20 + DK24 TO DK28"],

      ]




df1Columns = ["GUID","Deck_Info"]
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema = df1Columns)

print("Given Dataframe")
df1.show(n=100, truncate=False)


""" Using UDF on SQL """

spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("native_scala_extract_num_udf", "com.help.udf.SplitExtractValues", ArrayType(StringType()))

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("given_table")

df1_array = sqlContext.sql("select GUID, native_scala_extract_num_udf(Deck_Info) as Deck_Info_Array from given_table")
print("Dataframe after applying UDF")
df1_array.show(n=100, truncate=False)

df1_array.createOrReplaceTempView("df1_array")
print("Dataframe after exploding the array column")
df1_exploded = sqlContext.sql("select GUID, explode(Deck_Info_Array) as Deck_Info from df1_array")
df1_exploded.show(n=100, truncate=False)
```

Output :

```
Given Dataframe
+----+------------------------+
|GUID|Deck_Info               |
+----+------------------------+
|391 |DK1 , DK2               |
|392 |DK3 & DK4               |
|393 |DK5 / 6                 |
|394 |DK7 & 8                 |
|395 |DK9 , 10 & 11           |
|396 |DK12 + DK13             |
|397 |DK14.DK15               |
|398 |DK16 - DK18             |
|399 |DK18 TO DK20            |
|3990|DK18     to    DK20     |
|400 |DK16-DK20 + DK24 TO DK28|
+----+------------------------+

Dataframe after applying UDF
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|GUID|Deck_Info_Array                                             |
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+
|391 |[DK1, DK2]                                                  |
|392 |[DK3, DK4]                                                  |
|393 |[DK5, DK6]                                                  |
|394 |[DK7, DK8]                                                  |
|395 |[DK9, DK10, DK11]                                           |
|396 |[DK12, DK13]                                                |
|397 |[DK14, DK15]                                                |
|398 |[DK16, DK17, DK18]                                          |
|399 |[DK18, DK19, DK20]                                          |
|3990|[DK18, DK19, DK20]                                          |
|400 |[DK16, DK17, DK18, DK19, DK20, DK24, DK25, DK26, DK27, DK28]|
+----+------------------------------------------------------------+

Dataframe after exploding the array column
+----+---------+
|GUID|Deck_Info|
+----+---------+
|391 |DK1      |
|391 |DK2      |
|392 |DK3      |
|392 |DK4      |
|393 |DK5      |
|393 |DK6      |
|394 |DK7      |
|394 |DK8      |
|395 |DK9      |
|395 |DK10     |
|395 |DK11     |
|396 |DK12     |
|396 |DK13     |
|397 |DK14     |
|397 |DK15     |
|398 |DK16     |
|398 |DK17     |
|398 |DK18     |
|399 |DK18     |
|399 |DK19     |
|399 |DK20     |
|3990|DK18     |
|3990|DK19     |
|3990|DK20     |
|400 |DK16     |
|400 |DK17     |
|400 |DK18     |
|400 |DK19     |
|400 |DK20     |
|400 |DK24     |
|400 |DK25     |
|400 |DK26     |
|400 |DK27     |
|400 |DK28     |
+----+---------+
```